# Decrease pixel size of all current squares

Tags: javascript, dom, pixel

I wrote a function to decrease the size of all squares currently by a random int 5-15 for example reduce all squares by 7 pixels , the function must not reduce a square if the reduction would make its size less than 2x2. In this case I can either leave the square as is or simply remove it entirely.

Heres my function although it doesnt work the squares just keep getting smaller at one point just stop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8POY.png)

```
function px1down(){

    var allsquares = document.querySelectorAll("#squarearea div");
    var ranpixsize = getRndInteger(5,15);
    for (var i = 0; i<allsquares.length; i++){


        allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10) - ranpixsize + 'px';
        allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10) - ranpixsize + 'px';

        if(allsquares[i].style.height * allsquares[i].style.width < 4 + 'px'){
            allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10);
            allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10);
            alert('you cannot reduce the score to less than 2x2 pixels!');
        }

    }
}
```

... additionally I have wrote a function to increase pixel size but it ends up making squares which go out of the 700x300 rectangle div that the squares are inclosed in here is the code for that any suggestions?

```
function px1(){

    var allsquares = document.querySelectorAll("#squarearea div");
    var ranpixsize = getRndInteger(5,15);
    for (var i = 0; i<allsquares.length; i++){

        allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10) + ranpixsize + 'px';
        allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10) + ranpixsize + 'px';


      if(allsquares[i].style.left < 0 + 'px'){
            allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10);
            allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10);
        }
        else if(allsquares[i].style.top < 0 + 'px'){
            allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10);
            allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10);
        }
        else if(allsquares[i].style.width>700 + 'px'){
            allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10);
            allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10);
        }
        else if(allsquares[i].style.height>300 + 'px'){
            allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.width, 10);
            allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares[i].style.height, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better post a live demo

Comment: this is all wrong, cpu hungry and the most inefficient approach possible. and will trigger hundreds of thousands redraw requests per second on top of it. Plus the size manipulation of elements is linear not instant and in sync.

Comment: so what are your suggestions, and I will post an image.

Comment: I have posted an image any help